# Is every element of $E$ algebraic over $F(S)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, independence, transcendental-numbers

We have the set $E/F$.

Suppose that $S\subseteq T\subseteq E$ and that every element of $E$ is algebraic over $F(T)$ and that $S$ is algebraically independent over $F$.

Does it follow that every element of $E$ is algebraic also over $F(S)$ ?

Comment: Is there an assumption on the inclusion $S\subseteq T$? For instance, do you want $F(T)$ to be algebraic over $F(S)$?

Comment: What kind of assumprion do you mean? If we would have that $F(T)$ is algebraic over $F(S)$ then we would have that $E$ is algebraic over $F(S)$, right? @Pierre-GuyPlamondon

Comment: Yes.  I just wanted to check that this wasn't the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be indeterminates, and let $E=F(X,Y)$.  Furthermore, let $S=\{X\}$ and $T=\{X, Y\}$.

Then $E=F(X,Y)$ is an algebraic extension of $F(T) = F(X,Y) = E$, but it is not algebraic over $F(S) = F(X)$.  Moreover, $S$ is algebraically independent over $F$.

Comment: Ah ok... I am looking at the following: 
$$$$
Let $E/F$ an extension, $S = \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\} \subseteq E$ algebraically independent over $F$ and $T \supseteq S$ a subset of $E$, that spans $E$ algebraically over $F$. 
Show that there exists a set $B$ between $S$ and $T$, that is a trancendental basis of $E/F$, as follows: 
Let $T\setminus S = \{\beta_1, \ldots  , \beta_m\}$. 
If $T = \emptyset$, then $B = S$ is the trancendental basis. 
Otherwise, we define $S_0 = S$ and for $i = 1, \ldots , m$,

Comment: $$S_i=\left\{\begin{matrix}
S_{i-1} & \text{ if } \beta_i \text{ is algebraic } /F(S_{i-1})\\ 
S_{i-1}\cup \{\beta_i\} & \text{ if } \beta_i \text{ is not algebraic } /F(S_{i-1}) 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Show that $B = S_m$ is a trancendental basis of $E/F$.

$$$$

Suppose that $T\neq \emptyset$, then if all the $\beta_i$ are algebraic over $F(S_{i-1})$ then $B=S_m=S_{m-1}=\ldots =S_0=S$, right? Then $B$ is algebraicly independent over $F$. To show that it is a trancendental basis, we have to show that $B$ spans $E$ algebraically over $F$, right? But how?

Comment: @MaryStar  This seems to be correct.

Comment: But how can we show that $B$ spans $E$ algebraically over $F$. Or do use the other condition that a set is a trancendental basis, i.e., that this set is maximal among all the subsets of $E$ that are $F$-algebraiclly independent?

Comment: @MaryStar  By your construction, all elements of $T$ are algebraic over $F(B)$.  Since $E$ is algebraic over $F(T)$, the result follows.

Comment: How do we conclude that all the elements of $T$ are algebraic over $F(B)$ ? I got stuck right now...

Comment: @MaryStar  How can they not be? By construction, every $\beta_i$ is algebraic over $F(S_{i-1})$, so *a fortiori*, it is algebraic over $F(B)$.

Comment: Ahh ok!! I see!! Then the other case is to consider that at least one of the $\beta_i$'s is not algebraic over $F(S_{i-1})$, right? We have then that $S_i=S_{i-1}\cup \{\beta_i\}$. Does it hold then that $B=S_m=S\cup \{\beta_i\}$ ?

Comment: How can we show in that case that  B spans E algebraically over F?

Comment: It holds that all the elements of $T$ are algebraic over $F(B)=F(S\cup \{\beta_i\})$, and we use the same argument as above. is this correct?